# How to make possible having redundant properties in Model or possibility to add to references in one time

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a model Restriction:

```
  public string portefeuille
  public int AssetID {get;set;}
  public int SegmentID {get;set;}
  public int SubAssetID {get;set;}
  public int Min {get;set;}
  public int Max {get;set;}
```

And I want to have the possibility to have AssetID, SegmentID and SubAssetID twice to let the user to fill 2 times this information and then submitting the reference, or maybe if it is not possible the possibility to add two reference of Restriction in one time.

Does somebody have an idea ?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Change `int AssetID` to `List<int> AssetID`?

Comment: No I have to keep the same structure because I have DropDownlist for each of them

Answer (score 0):

Simply create another viewmodel for that issue.

```
public sealed class Restriction
{
    public sealed class Asset
    {
        public int AssetId { get; set; }
        public int SegmentId { get; set; }
        public int SubAssetId { get; set; }
    }

    public string Portefeuille { get; set; }
    public int Min { get; set; }
    public int Max { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Asset AssetOne { get; set; }

    // Not required and, therefore, optional.
    public Asset AssetTwo { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but what does it mean sealed ?

Comment: Nested public classes are against framework design guidelines if it needs to be instantiated in client code. Any reason for using nested class?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel the answer is not about nesting.

Comment: @intern [Here you go](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=C%23%20sealed&safe=off).

Comment: I know answer is not about nesting, but your answer contains nested class. If there is any good reasons behind it I'll be happy to get educated about that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that there will not be more than two AssedID you can create two AssetIDs in model.

The second way is to create as paul wrote List AssetID which will allow you to add more than one AssetId to the model.

The third way is to use additional class as

```
public class Restrictions
{
    public List<Restricion> RestricionsList {get;set;}
}
```

and then use it on page.

Hope this helps.

Comment: for the first proposition it is impossible to have the same name in the same model so I don't see how do see this ?  Second solution I don't know who is Paul nobody comment named paul who comment in this page! Finally third solution impossible too so I don't understand why say all this..

Comment: 1) you can create AssetID1 and AssetID2 2) Paul commented your question, not answer but comment 3) it is possible if you build properly view